# Beginner: Add methods to FRACTION class

Tags: objective-c

I've got a little extra assignment that I just cannot wrap my head around. I want to add the following methods to the Fraction class to round out the arithmetic operations on fractions. Reduce the result within the method in each case:

```
//Subtract argument from receiver
-( Fraction * ) subtract:  (Fraction *) f;

//Multiply receiver by argument
-( Fraction * ) multiply (Fraction *) f;

//Divide receiver by argument
-( Fraction * ) divide (Fraction *) f;
```

A nudge in the right direction, or more specific code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's stopping you from putting them in like any other method?

Answer (score 1):

SO doesn't provide homework answers... but maybe a nudge

Your `Fraction` class must provide properties, or instance variables, for the numerator and denominator. Given those just due the normal math as you would by hand.

To reduce a fraction you need to find the greatest common divisor, usually abbreviated GCD, of the numerator and denominator. If you don't know the GCD algorithm a book, or Google, will tell you.

And if after you've written code you can't get it to work you can come back to SO with a code-level question.

HTH

Comment: So I have created a Fraction.h, Fraction.m, and main.m that creates the class, it's implementation, and the main program. My problem now is I cannot figure how to compile in GNUstep so that main.m points to Fraction.h. I usually use this command "gcc -o ProgramName FileName.m -I /gnustep/system/library/headers -L /gnustep/system/library/libraries" to compile, but have found next to nothing what command to use now.

Comment: Maybe "gcc ... main.m Fraction.m ..."? You can pass a compiler more than one source file - see the gcc documentation.

Comment: Hmm, I will give that a try. I've also been told that I should just throw it all into one large program and just compile it like that.

Comment: "throw it all into one large program" - no. You obviously need to go and do so reading, any decent text on programming should cover the basics of how to compile. Understand the principles and then adapting to any compiler is just a small step. But if you get stuck ask a new question on SO, showing what you've tried etc.

Comment: Well I have looked, and my textbook only explains how to compile with Xcode so I'm kind of doing this on the fly. After seeing how much easier Xcode is to use than GNUstep, I think I'm just going to use them.